# Sessão expira frequentemente no iPad

Tags: bug, suporte, mobile, ipad

De uns tempos para cá, reparei que é bem comum a sessão do site expirar quando navego pelo Safari do iPad ou pelo celular. Às vezes isso ocorre várias vezes por dia, e chega a acontecer num intervalo de menos de uma hora. No computador a sessão raramente expira.

Isso é proposital? Não sei dizer se isso também ocorre em outros sites, já que o SOpt é o único que uso com tanta frequência.

---

Talvez esteja relacionado ao login do chat, que falha muito em mobile. Agora há pouco perdi uma sessão recém iniciada no site imediatamente após entrar no chat dos moderadores.

Comment: Safari, Chrome, Dolphin ou Opera? Eu sei que não tem haver com o a questão, mas experimentou o app oficial :) eu pessoalmente acho ele muito bom (apesar de faltar algumas coisas).

Comment: Já agora a app oficial não permite ver as questões e respostas apagadas. Ainda ontem recebi notificação de uma resposta apagada, e não consegui ver.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É no Safari, atualizei a pergunta. Vou tentar usar o Chrome um tempo para ver como ele se comporta. Sobre o app oficial, eu uso, é excelente. Mas não tem ferramentas de moderador, então preciso usar muito o browser.

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou tentar usar hoje no IPhone pelo Safari ou Chrome, infelizmente eu não tenho um MAC para usar o Console e analisar os Cookies, mas se você tiver, poderia fazer este teste? É possivel pelo MAC verificar o WebConsole e assim verficar como o Cookie é setado no momento da autenticação.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vou tentar arranjar um tempo pra testar isso. É que geralmente quando navego no iPad ou iPhone é porque não estou podendo parar na frente do computador...

Comment: No iPad sempre quando eu entro está deslogado, já faz tempo que não logo mais por ele, atualmente estou preferindo usar o app oficial Stack Exchange, tanto pra Android quanto pra iOS, é legal.

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois testes que podem ser feitos para determinar se é proposital ou um bug da autenticação das comunidades:

### Web Inspector com iPad/iPhone

1. No iPad/iPhone, vá até <kbd>Configurações</kbd> > <kbd>Safari</kbd> > <kbd>Avançado</kbd> e habilite o "Web Inspec­tor"
2. Abra o Safari do iPad/iPhone na página de uma comunidade StackExchange (no caso o SOpt)
3. Conecte o seu iPad/iPhone ao seu MAC
4. É provável que o console "abra", mas se não abrir então inicie o Safari do MAC e abra o Console/Inspetor, acredito que vai aparecer na "barra de ferramentas" (no topo) um botão chamado "Desenvolvedor" ou em inglês "Developer", clique nele e procure o seu iPad/iPhone (deve estar um nome como `iPhone de Guilherme`)

### Usando o navegador [Dolphin](http://dolphin.com/)

Outro teste que pode ser feito para não necessitar de um "MAC" é abrir a comunidade do "SE" desejada pelo navegador Dolphin usando o `user-agent` para Desktop (o Chrome tem está opção, mas acho que se ele fechar o `user-agent` volta a ser mobile --não tenho certeza), para fazer isto, siga os passos:

1. Clique no icone a direita do desenho do golfinho
2. Vá até <kbd>Settings</kbd> e habilite "Desktop Mode"
3. Acesse sua comunidade do SE.

   - Se o problema de perda de sessão ocorrer, então realmente é uma falha nas comunidades do "SE"
   - Se *não* ocorrer perda de sessão é bem provável que seja um "bloqueio" do proposital para dispositivos mobiles (talvez por segurança).

> **Nota:** Se você notar que o problema ocorre somente com um dos navegadores (chrome ou Safari) é provável que o armazenamento esteja no limite. Talvez uma "limpeza" faça voltar a funcionar.

Comment: Ainda não consegui testar esse procedimento (por preguiça, admito). Mas digo que usei o Chrome durante 2 dias e o problema não aconteceu.

Comment: @bfavaretto você chegou a limpar os dados de navegação anteriormente, poderia ter sido algum limite do armazenamento

Comment: Boa hipótese, porque acho que nunca limpei os dados de navegação! E essa é fácil de testar até pra preguiçoso :P

Comment: Testei limpar os dados de navegação, mas não resolveu. Durou menos de 48 horas, e o login seguinte durou apenas alguns minutos. Vou ter de investigar mais a fundo com as suas dicas mesmo.