# Você precisa estar logado para bater papo?

Tags: suporte, chat

Eu sempre usei o bate-papo no meu dispositivo móvel. Então, quando tentei interagir a pouco tempo, ele diz que eu não estou logado, portanto não posso bater papo:

[image: you need to be logged to chat]

Mas eu tenho certeza de que eu não estou exatamente *deslogado*:

[image: estou logado sim senhor]

Então, por acaso o login do chat não é o login que eu uso para acessar minha conta no SOpt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creio eu que existe mais de um meio de login, no caso eu uso uma conta da *Stack Exchange*, então as contas em diferentes sites da rede e chats são meio que vinculadas, no geral é isso, são sites diferentes, mas que compartilham alguns dados. Se esta autenticado por terceiros, como facebook ou google, talvez funcione um pouco diferente, o que quero dizer é que cada site tem sua propria sessão, eu tenho conta em uns 5 sites diferentes da rede, todos compartilham os mesmos dados, mas eu não preciso estar logado em todos.

Outro problema é que sendo celular, existem algumas limitações no tempo de sessão, veja esta postagem mais antiga:

- [Sessão expira frequentemente no iPad](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2385/3635)